# Stumped by list, string manipulation issue

Tags: coldfusion

Given the following list (#oldList#): 
`category1_item1, category1_item2, category2_item1, category3_item1, category3_item2"`

How can I create the following list (#newList#)?:
`category1[item1&item2],category2[item1],category3[item1&item2]`?

This is what I have so far:

```
<cfset newList = "">
<cfset category = "">

<cfloop list="#oldList#" index="listElement">
    <cfset endPos = find("_", listElement)>
    <cfset listElementCategory = left(listElement, endPos)>
    <cfset listElementItem = replace(listElement, listElementCategory, "")>

    <cfif listElementCategory is not category>
        <cfset modifiedElement = replace(listElementCategory, "_", "") & "[" & listElementItem>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset modifiedElement = "&" & listElementItem>
    </cfif>

    <cfset category = listElementCategory>

    <cfset newList = newList & modifiedElement>
</cfloop>
```

This code results in:
`category1[item1&item2category2[item1category3[item1&item2`

I just can't figure out how to close each "grouping" of items with "],".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfset newList = "">
<cfset category = "">

<cfloop list="#oldList#" index="listElement">
    <cfset endPos = find("_", listElement)>
    <cfset listElementCategory = left(listElement, endPos)>
    <cfset listElementItem = replace(listElement, listElementCategory, "")>

    <cfif listElementCategory is not category>
        <cfif category is not "">
            <!--- category has changed and this isn't the first record, so close previous category --->
             <cfset newList = newList & "],">  
        </cfif>
        <cfset modifiedElement = replace(listElementCategory, "_", "") & "[" & listElementItem>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset modifiedElement = "&" & listElementItem>
    </cfif>

    <cfset category = listElementCategory>

    <cfset newList = newList & modifiedElement>
</cfloop>
```

Note I just added this block:

```
<cfif category is not "">
   <!--- category has changed and this isn't the first record, so close previous category --->
   <cfset newList = newList & "],">  
</cfif>
```

Edit:

Almost forgot the end of the loop!  After the `</cfloop>` close the brackets like:

```
<cfif category is not "">
   <!--- close the final bracket since we have at least one record --->
   <cfset newList = newList & "]">  
</cfif>
```

Comment: Implementing your edits result in the following: "category1[item1], category1[item2], category2[item1], category3[item1&item2]" -can't figure out why category1 is repeated. So close!